# Multiple GET actions

Tags: asp.net-web-api, url-routing

I'm creating the following controller:

```
public FoosController : ApiController
{
    public IQueryable Get()
    {
        return AnODataQueryableListOfFoos();
    }

    public void Delete(Guid id)
    {
        DeleteTheFooWithId(id);
    }

    public IQueryable<Bar> GetBars(Guid id)
    {
        var foo = GetFooById(id);
        return AnODataQueryableListOfBarsForThisFoo(foo);
    }

    public IEnumerable ProjectedBars(Guid id)
    {
        var foo = GetFooById(id);
        return foo.Qux
            ? OneProjectionOfBars(foo)
            : AnotherProjectionOfBars(foo);
    }
}
```

(a list of Bars can be thought of as the "content" of Foo...)

It was my intention to use the following URLs:

```
GET /api/Foos                         -> Get
GET /api/Foos/SOME_GUID/Bars          -> GetBars
GET /api/Foos/SOME_GUID/ProjectedBars -> GetProjectedBars
DELETE /api/Foos/SOME_GUID            -> Delete
```

I tried with a couple of combinations of `[ActionName]` and custom routes, but there was always either a conflict or a 404.

What is the easiest way to get this working? I'd like to keep my routes generic (i.e. no controller-specific stuff) if possible. Other controllers use a more standard `/Stuff` - `Stuff/id` approach.

I'm also open to someone pointing out I'm completely misusing URLs. Improvements welcome.

Comment: Have you considered attribute-routing? Latest webapi as in-built support for it. You can read more about it here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: @KiranChalla I've thought about it. The main problem: it's not stable yet. I also tend to prefer convention-based implementations. And I'm willing to either adapt my design to standard conventions or tweak the conventions a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that Attribute Routing would be the best way to go, however you could try the following:

```
public FoosController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable Get()
    {
        return AnODataQueryableListOfFoos();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Bars")]
    public IQueryable<Bar> GetBars(Guid id)
    {
        var foo = GetFooById(id);
        return AnODataQueryableListOfBarsForThisFoo(foo);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("ProjectedBars")]
    public IEnumerable GetProjectedBars(Guid id)
    {
        var foo = GetFooById(id);
        return foo.Qux
            ? OneProjectionOfBars(foo)
            : AnotherProjectionOfBars(foo);
    }
}
```

and then use the following routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi2",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}"
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is n-depth sub-resources and the only real solution to this is the attribute routing provided in v2 of the Web API. Until it is released (which I believe will be soon), you can use RPC like approach:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("RPC", "rpc/{controller}/{id}/{action}");
```

You'll need to register this as the very first HTTP route, and use a prefix other than 'api' so it won't clash with the actual api/ routes.